# Is it OK to post questions about system administration on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I thought Stack Overflow was about programming. But I'm seeing quite a bit of questions that don't deal with programming. Instead they are about system administration, networking virtualization, [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine), etc. Are those questions legitimate or did they slip under the moderator's radar?

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922509/conntrack-tracking-private-tcp-sessions-between-vms
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864310/qemu-virt-manager-vm-hw-seen-as-laptop
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858012/permission-denied-when-connecting-to-libvirt-with-qemussh
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719185/finding-storage-pool-volume-path-using-virsh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right to be suspicious; [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is about programming, whereas [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) is about professional server administration, and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is for general software questions.

I took a look at the specific questions you mentioned and it does appear that they slipped under the radar. Specifically:

- [conntrack tracking private TCP sessions between VMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922509/conntrack-tracking-private-tcp-sessions-between-vms) — belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [Finding Storage pool/volume path using virsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719185/finding-storage-pool-volume-path-using-virsh) — belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [QEMU/virt-manager VM HW seen as laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864310/qemu-virt-manager-vm-hw-seen-as-laptop) — seems to be a more general software question, so belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- [Permission denied when connecting to libvirt with qemu+ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858012/permission-denied-when-connecting-to-libvirt-with-qemussh) — belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Where applicable, I have cast close votes.

Answer (score 5):

Funny thing about all of those questions; none of them have answers. Yep, they slipped under the radar.

System administration questions, except when they have programming content, are off-topic on Stack Overflow. They're on-topic on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) (but read their help pages first, to see how they like things).

Comment: They like things on Sever Fault?